# Access data in sql column in format of map

Tags: sql, redash

I have a column in sql table in which the data is of the format

```
table_name
 ----------------------------
| id | col_1                 |
|----------------------------|
| 1  | {key1=val1,key2=val2} |
| 1  | {key1=val3}           |
 ----------------------------
```

how do I access the values by checking if keys exist and use them in the aggregation after grouping by id?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: don't know about which SQL server which is being, used this is exposed via redash, is there a way to find that info using query tried Select @@VERSION but not working